# Using Grapher, how to edit or enter data points directly in the graph with the mouse?

Tags: macos, grapher

I am a rookie Grapher user. I am creating 2D piecewise linear curves using Grapher. So far, I've only discovered how to enter or edit datapoints via the `Edit Points` button at the top of the graph. Editing the points using the keyboard is tedious, unfortunately. Is it possible to move points in the point set using the mouse, via drag-and-drop?

I'm getting the idea the answer is "no".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do that, but you can put your points in a file and then input the file. I find it much easier to input data using an editor than the boxes on Grapher. Give your file a name that ends in `.txt` and then you can go to *Import* and, after clicking on that, the frame that appears has an import button. When clicking on import, it opens a Finder window for you to select the file you want.

Comment: Thanks, I don’t have a particular problem with the edit box that pops up. And I suspect my use is not particularly mainstream. I’m using Grapher to create/visualize a response curve that gets imported into a application I’m developing in C#. I’m experimenting with a variety of curves, and was hoping to speed up the process by entering/editing the points graphically.